# Azure Linux container on Web app environmental variables

Tags: azure, docker, environment-variables, azure-web-app-service, containers

I have a configuration that runs a Node docker container on azure as a Webapp.
Everywhere i read it clearly says that App Settings ( environmental variables ) set to the Web app will be injected at runtime to the container, but it's clearly not the case for me.

> "When your app runs, the App Service app settings are injected into
> the process as environment variables automatically"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-environment-variables

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node

# Open SSH for Azure
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ssh
RUN echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd
RUN mkdir /run/sshd
COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/

# Copy resources
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./

# Run install
RUN npm install
COPY . .

# Copy startup script and make it executable
COPY startup.sh /app
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/app/startup.sh"]
```

**startup.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Start sshd"
/usr/sbin/sshd

echo "Start node"
node server.js
```

And still (as an example):

```
secret: process.env.ADDSEARCH_SECRET
```

And still  process.env.ADDSEARCH_SECRET clearly returns null. As well as all the reset of the variables

[image: Azure env image]

What am I missing?

Using it with build_args during the build step of the docker image works, but I really don't want to do it that way for several reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix the environment variable with `APPSETTING_`, e.g. `APPSETTING_ADDSEARCH_SECRET`.